# How to draw a half oval on a canvas

Tags: android, draw, paint, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a smiley on a canvas.
The mouth needs to look happy or not happy depending of a integer between 0-100. the following code draws the smiley:

```
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(getColorByIntesity(intesity));
    canvas.drawCircle(23, 23, 20, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(15, 15, 3, paint); //Left eye
    canvas.drawCircle(31, 15, 3, paint); //Right eye

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
    canvas.drawCircle(23, 23, 20, paint);

    if(intesity >= 55)
        canvas.drawArc(getMouthDrawingByIntesity(intesity), 180, 180, false, paint); //Mouth
    else if(intesity < 55)
        canvas.drawArc(getMouthDrawingByIntesity(intesity), 0, 180, false, paint); //Mouth
```

My method to draw a mouth does something like this atm:

```
  final RectF oval = new RectF();
    if(intesity < 5){
        oval.set(11, 12, 35, 35);
    } etc..
```

But the mouth looks really pixellated. Does anyone knows a better way to draw a curved line (halve of a oval)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

If that doesn´t do the trick use this:

```
paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thnx alot, it looks alot better now :)